# Question about the Riesz representation theorem for the Dual of $L^p(E)$ in Royden's Real Analysis 4th edition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg2nn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWwpR.png)

Here is part of the proof. I cannot understand the sentence concerning the uniqueness. Here is my question:

Denote $I_n=[-n,n]$. $T_n$ is a bounded linear functional defined on $L^p(I_n)$. By previous theorem (Theorem 5 in this section), there exists a $g\in L^q(I_n)$ s.t.  $T_n(f)=\int_{I_n}g_n\cdot f$ for all $f\in L^p(I_n)$.

Similarly, $T_{n+1}$ is a bounded linear functional defined on $L^p(I_{n+1})$, and there exists a $g\in L^q(I_{n+1})\subset L^q(I_{n})$ s.t.  $T_{n+1}(f)=\int_{I_{n+1}}g_{n+1}\cdot f$ for all $f\in L^p(I_{n+1})$.

Observe that $T_n(f)=T_{n+1}(f)$ for all $f\in L^p(I_{n+1})$, i.e., $\int_{I_n}g_n\cdot f=\int_{I_{n+1}}g_{n+1}\cdot f$ for all $f\in L^p(I_{n+1})\subset L^p(I_n)$.

How can we conclude that $g_{n+1}|_{I_n}=g_n$ almost surely? Note that the integral domain is not the same.

Comment: Since you know how to use mathjax, why make us chase two links?  Could you please transcribe the entire proof?

Comment: Because of uniqueness. That is $g_{n}$ is unique and $g_{n+1}*\chi_{I_{n}}$ is also good they must be the same almost everythere.

Comment: If I understood what your question is, the following might help. You can observe for example that considering all simple functions with support in $I_n$ you should get $\int_{I_n}g_n\cdot f=\int_{I_{n}}g_{n+1}\cdot f$, which gives $g_n=g_{n+1}$ a.e. In $I_n$.